# How to select a substring from Oracle blob field

Tags: oracle

I need to get part of a blob field which has some json data. one part of the blob is like this `CustomData:{HDFC;1;0;sent}` . I need separate values after `CustomData` like I need to get `HDFC`, `1`, `0`, sent separately.

This is what I have tried in two separate queries which works:

This gives me index of `CustomData` within `payment_data` blob field for example it returns `11000`

```
select dbms_lob.instr(payment_data, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('CustomData')) 
from table_x;
```

I am specifying 3rd parameter as what first query returned + length of test `CustomData:` to get `{HDFC;1;0;sent}`

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(dbms_lob.substr(payment_data,1000,11011)) 
from table_x;
```

Problem is I need to take dynamic offset in 2nd query and not run 1st query as individual. Specifying dynamic offset is not working with dbms_lob.substr() function. Any suggestions how can I combine these two queries into one?

Once I get `{HDFC;1;0;sent}`, I also need to get these delimited values separately, so combining these three into one would even be better if someone can help with it. I can use regexp_substr to get delimited text once I get first two combined.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want extract text data from blob first u need convert it to clob using dbms_lob.converttoclob.
2. If you have Oracle 12c or higher you may use JSON SQL functions, for example, [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62).
3. If your Oracle version between 10 and 11 you may use regex functions or instr + substr if your version less than 10.

Comment: We are on Oracle 11 and I have tried using instr+ substr to do the work as indicated in my question, executing these 2 queries separately is working. Problem is substr doesn't seem to take dynamic offset so I am not able to combine these 2 queries into 1.